# How to loop over acyclic directed graph in R to find which vertex should be removed to maximize distance?

Tags: r, graph-algorithm, mathematical-optimization

Because I think my primary obstacle is coding this problem I put it here rather than on MSE. I'll move it over if that was incorrect.

I have a matrix, `m`, that I constructed representing an acyclic directed graph where the matrix entries are the distances between nodes. For example [and to confirm I constructed it correctly], vertex 1 goes to vertices 2, 3, 4 with distances of 3, 4, and 4 respectively. And vertex 12 goes to vertices 13, 16, 19 with distances of 6, 2, 6 respectively.

```
      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20
 [1,]  0  3  4  4  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [2,]  0  0  0  0  3  5  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [3,]  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [4,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  5  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [5,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [6,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [7,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  6   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [8,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   3   0   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [9,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   3   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
[10,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
[11,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   3   0   0   0   0   0
[12,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   6   0   0   2   0   0   6   0
[13,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
[14,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0
[15,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   1   0   0
[16,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   2   0
[17,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
[18,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3
[19,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4
[20,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I already went through and manually calculated a minimum distance path using a backwards recursion method (I'm not sure if it has a proper name) where it starts at the vertex 20 and then iteratively works its way back to vertex 1 where each iteration:

f(i) = min{s(i,j) + f(j)}
where i and j are vertices, s(i,j) is the edge length from vertex i to j, and f(j) is the minimum distance from vertex j to the terminal vertex.

```
f(20) = 0
f(19) = 4 + f(20) = 4
f(18) = 3 + f(20) = 3
f(17) = 2 + f(20) = 2
f(16) = min { 3 + f(18) | 2 + f(19) = 6
f(15) = min { 4 + f(17) | 1 + f(18)  = 4
f(14) = 5 + f(17) = 7
f(13) = 1 + f(15) = 5
f(12) = min { 6 + f(13) | 2 + f(16) | 6 + f(19) = 8
f(11) = min { 1 + f(14) | 3 + f(15) = 7 
f(10) = min \{ 3 + f(13) = 8
f(9) = min { 3 + f(11) | 3 + f(13) = 8
f(8) = min { 3 + f(10) | 5 + f(12) = 11
f(7) = min { 6 + f(9) | 4 + f(10) = 12
f(6) = 3 + f(9) = 11
f(5) = 8 + f(14) = 15
f(4) = 5 + f(8) = 16
f(3) = min { 2 + f(6) | 2 + f(7) = 13
f(2) = min { 3 + f(5) | 5 f(6) = 16
f(1) = min { 3 + f(2) | 4 + f(3) | 4 + f(4) = 17
```

Which identifies the minimal path as 1 - 3 - 6 - 9 - 13 - 15 - 18 - 20. Now, I'm trying to find which single edge to remove that would maximize the distance from vertex 1 to vertex 20 without using an `R` package [if there is one] so I can see what's going on. I'm really uncertain how to get started on this and know it's next to nothing, but started with something like:

```
for (i in nrow(t)-1:2) {
  for (j in ncol(t):1) {
    if k != 0 { s[j] <- k }

  }
}
```

How would I go about taking the minimum of the sum of the distance from vertex i to j and the longest distance from j to the terminal node as done manually above?

Comment: This sounds like an attacker/defender model which relies on optimization techniques to solve. An easy (but grossly inefficient) way would be for you to iterate over each leg (used), remove one, and re-calculate. Rinse, lather, repeat, recognizing that this will likely take you a long time. This is one reason optimization engines are written, often with a specific algebraic modeling language and proprietary libraries to solve much faster and in the face of other factors. R is not meant for this type of work. Base R even less so.

Comment: Have you tried using the igraph package at least for your graph data structure? Most of the standard graph algorithms are available, you should be able to build on that rather than crafting things manually.

Comment: I hadn't tried `igraph` except for plotting. Even if I wasn't able to code the entire new problem in whole (figure out which node to take out to maximize), I was having trouble just coding what I did above manually.